# More efficient way to loop through lines in shell

Tags: bash, performance, shell, loops

I've come to learn that looping through lines in bash by

```
while read line; do stuff; done <file
```

Is not the most efficient way to do it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

What is a more time/resource efficient method?

Comment: awk            (this is a filler)

Comment: Depends on whether `stuff` is calling other shell tools, or just processing the text.

Comment: Shell if for launching your OS provided commands and piping their inputs and outputs wherever they are needed at. For reading data from files and processing it use tools that are made for that particular job. Don't confuse shell as text processor or programming language.

Comment: Instead of linking one question (where the answers could be disputable and dependant on the usage scenario) you should post your problem, where you need speed-up the loop. _Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth_

Comment: This *is* the most efficient way to read a file in shell. The question is really, should you be iterating over the file in shell *at all*? General rule of thumb: if you are doing anything more complex with the data you are reading than passing it as arguments to another program, you're probably using the shell when you shouldn't be.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `time`'d example using Bash and awk. I have 1 million records in a file:

```
$ wc -l 1M
1000000 1M
```

Counting it's records with bash, using `while read`:

```
$ time while read -r line ; do ((i++)) ; done < 1M ; echo $i

real    0m12.440s
user    0m11.548s
sys     0m0.884s
1000000
```

Using `let "i++"` took 15.627 secs (real) and NOPing with `do : ;` 10.466. Using awk:

```
$ time awk '{i++}END{print i}' 1M
1000000

real    0m0.128s
user    0m0.128s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it depends on what you're doing.

The reason it's inefficient is that everything runs in its own process. Depending on what you are doing, that may or may not be a big deal.

If what you want to do in the loop is run another shell process, you won't get any gain from eliminating the loop. If you can do what you need without the need for a loop, you could get a gain.

Answer (score 0):

awk? Perl? C(++)? Of course it depends on if you're interested in CPU time or programmer time, and the latter depends on what the programmer is used to using.

The top answer to the question you linked to pretty much explains that the biggest problem is spawning external processes for simple text processing tasks. E.g. running an instance of `awk` or a pipeline of `sed` and `cut` for each single line just to get a part of the string is silly.

If you want to stay in shell, use the string processing [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (`${var#word}`, `${var:n:m}`, `${var/search/replace}` etc.) and other shell features as much as you can. If you see yourself running a set of commands for each input line, it's time to think the structure of the script again. Most of the text processing commands can process a whole file with one execution, so use that.

A trivial/silly example:

```
while read -r line; do
    x=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    somecmd "$x"
done < file
```

would be better as

```
awk < file '{print $2}' | while read -r x ; do somecmd "$x" ; done
```

Comment: Using `awk` at *all* here is wrong; `read -r _ x _` will split the line into the necessary fields.

Comment: @chepner, yes, I did say something about using the shell's functionality, and I did say the example was trivial. (added "silly" now, that was the other word I was thinking of.)

Answer (score 0):

Choose between `awk` or `perl` both are efficient

[image: awk or perl]